# Problem inserting rows in SQL table, teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have some trouble when creating a table in SQL/teradata, as the simple following code successfully creates a table but does not insert the data into it :

```
CREATE VOLATILE MULTISET TABLE tablename
(FIRSTVARIABLE INTEGER, SECONDVARIABLE INTEGER);

INSERT INTO tablename VALUES(1,2);
```

Do you have any idea what could go wrong with such a simple code ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE VOLATILE MULTISET TABLE tablename
(FIRSTVARIABLE INTEGER, SECONDVARIABLE INTEGER)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
```

Default is `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` and you must be auto-commiting your statements

Comment: For the life of me, I have never understood why Teradata thinks you might want to create a volatile table that doesn't keep rows you insert...

Comment: @Andrew - oddly enough, ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS is the ANSI/ISO SQL standard behavior for temporary tables.